# Windows 8 BottomAppBar change icon in code

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, appbar

im developing a metro app for windows 8 and I have big difficulties to change icon in BottomAppBar in code. I want to have there icon which indicates that sounds are enabled and when you tap it I want it to change to another icon which indicates that sounds are disabled

```
<Button x:Name="SoundsAppBarIcon" 
Style="{StaticResource SoundsEnabledAppBarButtonStyle}"
Tag="Sounds"
Click="SoundsAppBarIcon_Click"/>
```

In that style there is `<Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE189;"/>` and I dont know what this `&#xE189` mean.

Anyway I tried to do something like this but it didnt work either

```
<Button x:Name="SoundsAppBarIcon" 
        Tag="Sounds"
        Click="SoundsAppBarIcon_Click">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="Assets/Images/SoundsDisabled.png"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

& #xE189; is the character code.

You can get more icons by opening Character Map, selecting "Segoe UI Symbol" for the font, and then scrolling down to find one you like. Microsoft recommends using these icons, rather than image files, for uniformity amongst apps.

Once you find an icon you like from the Character Map, simply copy it and paste it into your content setter in the XAML. Don't worry about it appearing as a box with a question mark in it within the code, it will display correctly within the app.

Comment: thank you, I couldnt find icon i would like to use in "Seoge UI Symbol" charackters. Is there a way how to change than icon to a png picture ?

Comment: You would need to use a different button template and have images for different button states. Look up ImageButton in WinRT XAML Toolkit.

Comment: Here is how you do it btw: http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/25/example-metro-app-winrt-how-to-add-more-segoe-ui-symbol-symbols-as-icons/ And as for other icons, I've used syncfusion Metro studio http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio , the XAML version of the icons. Super-nice, and last time I checked free licence as well. TannerJS is spot on in RE to recommendations.